Issue with Nvidia driver on a new machine running 24.04
Installed today Ubuntu on a new machine with a 4060TI and MSI B550 Tomahawk Board. Wasn't super easy but I managed to get it working fine.
Though something happened that broke the boot with message:
> Failed to query Nvidia devices. Please ensure that the NVIDIAdevice
> files (/dev/nvidia*) exist, and that user 122 has read and
> writepermission for those files. Failed to start
> nvidia.persistenced;service - NVIDIA perisstence Daemon GDM: Gdm
> Session : no session desktop files installed, aborting ... Failed to
> start plymouth-quit.service - Terminate Plymouth boot screen

> nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from
> proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.

Because I couldn't solve, I have reinstalled Ubuntu.
Though it happens again when installing Veracrypt and fuse + pcscd dependencies.
I used Mokutil to reinstall the keys with guidance from a AI model, with no luck.
Disabling Secure Boot neither fixes it.
I can reinstall but I am afraid the problem comes up again in the future with valuable data on my SSD drive...
